# How to control Android camera exposure time

Tags: android, camera

I want to set the Android phone's **exposure time** to **not more than 1/10000s**.But I just can set the **Exposure compensation and ISO** through code

Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();       parameters.setExposureCompensation(parameters.getMinExposureCompensation());
parameters.set("iso", "800");

This can reduce the automatic exposure time to some extent,but it not work well, I found when I set the **zoom size** of the phone camera to larger, the exposure time can be smaller. And when I touch **my phone system camera** to make it focus on the light automatically, the exposure time can be smaller. I want my custom camera can reduce exposure time just like my system phone.I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?